# There is more then one Homology Theory for spaces, which are not Hausdorff

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

All of us know: if we have a CW-complex, then using an arbitrary homology theory (with the axioms of disjoint union and dimension axiom) we always get the same homology groups up to an isomorphism.

Is it true, that if I have a space, which is not Hausdorff (of course no CW-complex), then there are two homology theories with non isomorphic groups?

Generalized: if we have a top. space, such that all homology groups are isomorphic, given arbitrary two homology theories, does the top. spaces carry a CW-structure?

May the force and Hatcher be with you. ;-)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. There are numerous homology theories for topological spaces, and they are not all isomorphic to each other.

Comment: But if you have a CW-complex and the homology theories satisfy the disjoint union axiom and the dimension axiom, the homology groups are isomorphic.

Comment: "All of us know" Let's be fair to those among us for which terms like "CW-complex" and "homology theory" are considered far outside the realms of "daily life" ...

Comment: Each choice of coefficient group leads to a different homology theory. So, if you take the dimension axiom to be $H_0(pt) = A$, $H_n(pt) = 0$ for $n>0$ and $A$ an abelian group, you get a different theory for each choice of $A$. But this is in some sense the only variety possible, at least when considering CW-complexes.

Comment: @wckronholm The question seems to be the following: For two functors $H^\ast$, $\hat{H}^\ast$ from the category of CW-pairs to $R\mathbf{-Mod}$ satisfying the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms, it is known that if $H^0(\mathrm{pt}) \cong \hat{H}^0(\mathrm{pt})$, then there is a natural isomorphism $H^\ast \Rightarrow \hat{H}^\ast$. Mebat is asking if this becomes false when we consider a category of spaces more general than CW-pairs.

Comment: You should be able to compare Cech (co)homology with singular: see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1750/can-anyone-give-me-a-good-example-of-two-interestingly-different-ordinary-cohomo

Comment: Your question certainly has content, but since most of homotopy theory agrees that inverting the $\pi_*$ equivalences gives the right homotopy category, the issue of Hausdorffness has not been heavily studied for a long time. Generaly people want a homology theory to be defined on the homotopy category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first question is no.

Because, consider the one-point space and the two-point space with the topology, that only the empty set and the entire space are open, then these spaces are homotopy equivalent, because all maps to the second space are continuos. But the second is not Hausdorff, but the first is a (almost trivial) CW-complex.

The Answer to the second part is no, too. This follows by the same example.

But this is in general not obvious.

Consider we have a topological space domintated by a CW-complex, then this space is homotopy equivalent to a CW-space[see Hatcher A.11], so all homology theories that satisfy the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms are up to an iso the same.

But this dominated space need not to have a CW-structure, this is the non obvious part. The interested guys will see stuff to Wall's finiteness obstruction and the universal obstruction in this setting. What a proof.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So, what you are trying to do in the second part is to show that the two-point space with indiscrete topology does not have a CW complex structure, right?